# A better way to create a custom vertex with QuickGraph?

Tags: c#, quickgraph

I'm looking to make a graph that has vertices with some custom properties. For instance, have a vertex called `"A"` that also has `x, y` coordinates associated with it.

I've done this by creating a class that holds its identifier a `string`, and two `ints`. To get the class to play nicely with the `AddEdge` function I overrode `.Equals` and `.GetHashCode` so that and two vertices with the same identifier are equal and have the same hash code regardless of any other properties (like the coordinates)

This seems to work fine, I was able to run the built in `DijkstraShortestPathAlgorithm` successfully.

## Question

My question is, is this the best way to go about it? It seems really inelegant. I end up writing really ugly lines like:

```
Edge<CustomVertex> a_e = new Edge<CustomVertex>(new CustomVertex("A"), new CustomVertex("E"));
graph.AddEdge(a_e);
```

Which I could easily make less ugly, but it just struck me that maybe what I'm doing is overkill.

I'm somewhat new to C#, and I've never used the QuickGraph (or Boost Graph) library before. I just want to attach simple properties to vertices. I was thinking I could also maintain a separate dictionary with the properties of each vertex, and leave the vertex class as a `string` instead of `CustomVertex`

Thoughts?

Full class:

```
class CustomVertex
{
    public String value { get; set; }

    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }

    public CustomVertex (String value){
        this.value = value;
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }

    public override bool Equals (object other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        CustomVertex other_cast = other as CustomVertex;
        if ((System.Object)other_cast == null)
            return false;

        return this.value == other_cast.value;
    }

    public bool Equals(CustomVertex other)
    {
        if ((object)other == null)
            return false;

        return this.value == other.value;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode ()
    {
        return this.value.GetHashCode ();
    }

    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

And creating the graph looks like

```
AdjacencyGraph<CustomVertex, Edge<CustomVertex>> graph = new AdjacencyGraph<CustomVertex, Edge<CustomVertex>>(true);

graph.AddVertex(new CustomVertex("A"));
```

Comment: based on my limited experience with QuikGraph, this really is the most elegant solution you can opt for